# Convert hexadecimal from socket to decimal

Tags: c, hex

In a server, I get the length of an image data first, then the image data via TCP socket. How can I convert the length (in hexadecimal) to decimal, so that I know how much image data I should read? (eg. 0x00 0x00 0x17 0xF0  to 6128 bytes)

```
char len[4];
char buf[1024];
int lengthbytes = 0;
int databytes = 0;
int readbytes = 0;

// receive the length of image data
lengthbytes = recv(clientSocket, len, sizeof(len), 0);

// how to convert binary hex data to length in bytes

// get all image data 
while ( readbytes < ??? ) {

    databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("image.jpg","wb");
    fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), pFile);

    readbytes += databytes;
}

fclose(pFile);
```

EDITED: This is the working one.

```
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t; // Required as I'm using Visual Studio 2005
uint32_t len;
char buf[1024];
int lengthbytes = 0;
int databytes = 0;
int readbytes = 0;

FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("new.jpg","wb");

// receive the length of image data
lengthbytes = recv(clientSocket, (char *)&len, sizeof(len), 0);

// using networkd endians to convert hexadecimal data to length in bytes
len = ntohl(len);

// get all image data 
while ( readbytes < len ) {
databytes = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), pFile);
readbytes += databytes;
}

fclose(pFile);
```

Comment: What does "binary hex data" mean? It's either binary or hex. Are you looking for something like `ntohl`? Where is the code that **writes** these 4 bytes to the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zero-terminate the number, so it becomes a string (assuming you send the digits as characters), you can use [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul).

---

If you send it as a binary 32-bit number, you already have it as you need it. You should just use a different data-type for it: `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t len;

/* Read the value */
recv(clientSocket, (char *) &len, sizeof(len));

/* Convert from network byte-order */
len = ntohl(len);
```

When designing a binary protocol you should always use the standard fixed-size data types, like `uint32_t` in the example above, and always send all non-textual data in network byte-order. This will make the protocol more portable between platforms. However, you don't have to convert the actual image data as that should already be in a platform-independent format, or just plain data bytes which doesn't have any byte-ordering issues.

Comment: Use network endian! Let's not encourage people to write x86 ints on the wire when htonl will keep things architecture independent.

Comment: @joachim i can't make it work... error C2664: 'recv' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'uint32_t' to 'char *'

Comment: @boogiedoll You're missing the address-of operator? You also might need to type-cast the pointer.